# How to print a formated date time from mysql timestamp in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'am trying to print my timestamp formated date & time from mysql database in php Codeigniter but this will give me a error message :

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

My code:

```
if ($userTasks) {
   foreach ($userTasks as $key) {
       echo time_convert($key->t_time);
   }
}


public function time_convert($timestamp){
   return date('l Y/m/d H:i', $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Use `strtotime` function on t_time, should do the trick.

Comment: did you check if  `$key->t_time` has a value?, how does it look like?

Comment: `$key->t_time` give me  `2020-07-01 20:46:23`

Comment: Actually you can use the built-in Time class of CI4: `new Time($key->t_time)`. More info: https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/libraries/time.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are codeigniter DateTime library and helper as well but I prefer using normal PHP for this basic functionalities.
Basic two ways:

1. Convert your mysql timestamp to Unix Timestamp using "strtotime()" and use "date()" function to convert unix timestamp to formatted date.

   > ```
   > $unix_ts=strtotime('2020-07-01 20:46:23');  
   > echo date("Y-m-d",$unix_ts);
   > ```
2. Create date object from mysql timestamp  using "create_date()" and use "date_format()" function which takes date object as its parameter.

   ```
   $date = date_create('2020-07-01 20:46:23');
   echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of two ways. First is `DATE FORMAT` function in your SQL, like this.

```
$this->db->select(' DATE_FORMAT(orderdate, '%Y-%m-%d') as orderDate')
```

To learn more about it [Read here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/)

Another way to it is through PHP
you can use PHP's **DateTime** class like this

```
    public function time_convert($timestamp){
       // Create datetime object
       phpDatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

      // return datetime in your  required format
      return phpDatetime->format('l Y/m/d H:i');
}
```